# Introduce left/right swipe gestures to a Javascript class toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch, swipe

I have a modal that has two panels. One is off canvas until it is triggered/toggled by clicking a link.

I've included an example showing this working but I was wondering is there away I can also toggle the classes using left/right swipes on touch devices? I tried a CSS approach using `scroll-snap` which wasn't as smooth as the current transitions I have + obviously it didn't update the class on the container.

In the example, if you click the "Trigger Cart" link the modal will slide into view and then you can use the vertical/red bar (Pair With...) to toggle between the two states ...how/can I introduce a swipe into that?

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html');
 const btnOpen = document.querySelector('.trigger-cart');
 const allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-head__close');

 btnOpen.addEventListener('click', e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   html.classList.add('cart-visible');
 });
 
 allCloseButtons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    html.classList.remove('cart-visible');

    setTimeout(function() {
        cart.classList.remove('cart-toggled');
    }, (320)); // Match with time it takes to close menu.
  });
});
 
 
 /* Toggle Class on Cart */

const cart = document.querySelector('.cart');
const toggle = document.querySelector('.cart__toggle');

const handleToggleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  cart.classList.toggle('cart-toggled');
};

const handleResize = () => {
  if (window.matchMedia(`(min-width: 64em)`).matches) {
    cart.classList.remove('cart-toggled');
  }
};

toggle.addEventListener('click', handleToggleClick);
window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.cart {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -375px;
  transition: right .24s ease-out;
  width: 375px;
}

.cart-visible .cart {
  right: 0;
  animation: example 1.28s ease;
}

.cart-head {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .24);
}

.cart-items {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .24);
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cart-foot {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .24);
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cart__main,
.cart__toggle,
.cart__upsell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.cart__main,
.cart__upsell {
  width: calc(100% - 48px);
}

.cart__main {
  margin: 0;
  transition: margin .24s ease-out;
}

.cart.cart-toggled .cart__main {
  margin-left: calc(-100% + 48px);
}

.cart.cart-toggled .cart__pag {
  margin-left: 48px;
}

.cart.cart-toggled .cart__pag-item:first-child {
  background: none;
}

.cart.cart-toggled .cart__pag-item:last-child {
  background: black;
}

.cart__toggle {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 0;
  width: 48px;
}

.cart__toggle-label {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.cart__pag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 0;
  transition: margin .24s ease-out;
  width: calc(100% - 64px);
}

.cart__pag-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  width: 8px;
}

.cart__pag-item:first-child {
  background: black;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%        {right: -375px;}
  40%       {right: 96px;}
  100%      {right: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <a href="" class="trigger-cart">Trigger Cart</a>
</div>

<div class="cart">
  
  <div class="cart__main">
    
    <div class="cart-head">
      <h2>Header</h2>
<!--       <a href="btn-close">x</a> -->
    </div>
    
    <div class="cart-items">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="cart-foot">
      <h2>Footer</h2>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="cart__toggle" id="toggle">
    <h4 class="cart__toggle-label">Pair with..</h4>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cart__upsell">
    
    <div class="cart-header">
      <h2>Pair With...</h2>
      <a href="btn-close">x</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="cart__pag">
    <div class="cart__pag-item"></div>
    <div class="cart__pag-item"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```